# how to add javascript/html codes inside php echo

Tags: php, html

I need the html td class inside the php echo for the javascript functionalities and scripts. The td class works well at first but when i insert it inside the php code it is not functioning anymore. Any ideas how to make it work?

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
        endforeach;
        if($exist==1)
        {
            echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$date1</td>
                <td>$m_time</td>
                <td>$mx_time</td>
                <td>$total_hrs</td>
                <td class="tbl-save"><img onclick="save(this);" id="<?php echo $list->id ?>" class="icon-save" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/save.png" width="15" height="15" title="Save"></td>
                <td class="tbl-edit"><i onclick="edit(this);" id="<?php echo $list->id ?>" class="icon-pencil"></td>                
            </tr>";
        }
        else
        {
        }?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you are using double quotes inside the echo statement, which terminate your string literal.

```
echo "<td class="something">";
     ^          ^
     |          |
The string    PHP thinks that the
literal be-   string literal ends
gins here     here.
```

In order to use double quotes inside a string literal, you can use the following options:

- Escaping the double quotes with a backslash: `\"`. The double quotes will be interpreted as literal double quote, due to the preceding backslash.
- Use single quotes to delimit the string:

  ```
  echo '<td class="something">';
  ```

But there are alternatives:

- Don't put HTML code in an PHP `echo` statement, only PHP variables:

  ```
  <td><?php echo $date1; ?></td>
  ```
- Bind your PHP variables to a custom template system and parse the output:

  ```
  <?php

  // Turn on output buffering. It will not send the output away,
  // but hold it for later use.
  ob_start();

  ?>

  <td>%date%</td>
  <td>%mtime%</td>

  <?php

  // Here we store the contents of the output buffer
  // into a variable.
  // The output buffer will contain this:
  // <td>%date%</td>
  // <td>%mtime%</td>
  $contents = ob_get_contents();

  // Now we need to replace some of our own custom
  // variables with the PHP variables.
  $search = array("%date%", "%mtime%");
  $replace = array($date, $m_time);
  $contents = str_replace($search, $replace, $contents);

  echo $contents;

  ?>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The root cause of your problem is that the double-quotes around your class name are terminating the echo string. You will need to escape them with backslashes.

For example:

```
echo "<td class="tbl-save">"
```

Should be instead:

```
echo "<td class=\"tbl-save\">"
```

Alternatively you could use a HEREDOC and not worry about escaping double quotes. For example:

```
echo <<<END
<td class="tbl-save">
END;
```

You can read up more about HEREDOCs here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

In general I would avoid mixing HTML and PHP as a best practice since it can make the code unyieldy to read and most IDEs lose the ability to syntax highlight the HTML inside your string. Consider using templating alternatives such as twing/smarty or MVC frameworks.
This wikipedia article lists the templating engines available you can choose from:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_template_engines

Answer (score 1):

you cant do echo "... class="tbl-save"... "

it has to be echo "... class='tbl-save'..."

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape slash () before all double quotes other than starting and ending double qoutes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the double quotes inside of `echo "";` or use single quotes inside of it. Or you can change `echo "";` to `echo '';`. The downside is you can't use variables inside, since they don't get parsed. You need to 'break' the string in order to use a variable `echo 'use of variable '.$variable.' mkay';`.

Also it's not necessary to do `<?php echo $variable; ?>`, since the variable anyway get parsed inside of double quotes and you didn't close the php tag before. But I would recommend you for the sake of readability to 'break' the string like above.

```
echo '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$date1.'</td>
            <td>'.$m_time.'</td>
            <td>'.$mx_time.'</td>
            <td>'.$total_hrs.'</td>
            <td class="tbl-save"><img onclick="save(this);" id="'.$list->id.'" class="icon-save" src="'.base_url().'images/save.png" width="15" height="15" title="Save"></td>
            <td class="tbl-edit"><i onclick="edit(this);" id="'.$list->id.'" class="icon-pencil"></td>                
        </tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use nested `<?php ?>` tag. Use single quotes for `echo ''` and double quotes inside it (eg, `id="id1"` and so on..).  Try something like below

```
if($exist==1)
    {
        echo '
        <tr>
            <td>$date1</td>
            <td>$m_time</td>
            <td>$mx_time</td>
            <td>$total_hrs</td>
            <td class="tbl-save">
                <img onclick="save(this);" id="'.$list->id.'" class="icon-save" src="'.base_url().'images/save.png" width="15" height="15" title="Save">
            </td>
            <td class="tbl-edit"><i onclick="edit(this);" id="'.$list->id.'" class="icon-pencil"></td>
        </tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax highlighter shows you what the problem is. Make sure your strings are properly escaped and terminated.

Also you have `<?php` tags within php strings.

```
<?php 
        endforeach;
        if($exist==1)
        {
            echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$date1</td>
                <td>$m_time</td>
                <td>$mx_time</td>
                <td>$total_hrs</td>
                <td class=\"tbl-save\"><img onclick=\"save(this);\" id=\"{$list->id}\" class=\"icon-save\" src=\"".base_url()."images/save.png\" width=\"15\" height=\"15\" title=\"Save\"></td>
                <td class=\"tbl-edit\"><i onclick=\"edit(this);\" id=\"{$list->id}\" class=\"icon-pencil\"></td>                
            </tr>";
        }
        else
        {
        }?>
```